# How to give permissions for Android with Cordova?

Tags: android, android-studio, cordova, plugins, configuration

I created a mobile application with Android. In my application I want to add permission requests for certain plugins that I used. After following the documentation and some blogs on the subject. when I generate the apk the installation works the application launches but the permissions do not work.

**Here is my config.xml file:**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.achabi_customer.achabi" version="1.0.0" 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" 
    xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0"
>
    <name>Achabi</name>
    <description>Achabi Customer App</description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="https://cordova.apache.org">
        Achabi Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />

    <preference name="SplashScreenBackgroundColor" value="#212A6B" />
    <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
    <preference name="BackgroundColor" value="#212A6B" />
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
    <preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false" />
    <preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" />
    <preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#ffc107" />
    <preference name="HeaderColor" value="#ffc107" />

    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-settings-hook" spec="~0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" spec="^7.0.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" spec="^8.0.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-media-capture" spec="^5.0.0" />

    <platform name="android">    
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        <preference name="AndroidWindowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon" value="[www/assets/android/mdpi.png]" />

        <icon src="www/assets/android/mdpi.png" density="mdpi" />
        <icon src="www/assets/android/ldpi.png" density="ldpi" />
        <icon src="www/assets/android/hdpi.png" density="hdpi" />
        <icon src="www/assets/android/xdpi.png" density="xhdpi" />
        <icon src="www/assets/android/xxdpi.png" density="xxhdpi" />

       <config-file mode="merge" parent="/*" target="AndroidManifest.xml">
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>    
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
            <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
            <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
        </config-file>
    </platform>

</widget>
```

**My AndroidManifest.xml file:**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="10000" android:versionName="1.0.0" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|uiMode" android:exported="true" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@style/Theme.App.SplashScreen" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <provider android:authorities="${applicationId}.cordova.plugin.camera.provider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true" android:name="org.apache.cordova.camera.FileProvider">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/camera_provider_paths" />
        </provider>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:maxSdkVersion="32" android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO" />
    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE" />
        </intent>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT" />
        </intent>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />
        </intent>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="com.android.camera.action.CROP" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/*" android:scheme="content" />
        </intent>
    </queries>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:maxSdkVersion="32" android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

For some permissions in Android, just having 'uses-permission' is not enough. These are considered runtime permissions, like 'CAMERA'. In your app you have to ask the user for permissions. Only when the user clicks ‘Allow’, the permission is granted.